# How do I prevent users from modifying AWS security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, identity-management

I've looked all over Google, and haven't found a solid solution yet that works. I have an environment set up in AWS where I do NOT want users to be able to make any changes to the EC2 security groups; these can ONLY be set via Terraform apply. I have the following policy that we tried applying to users, but it didn't prevent me from adding or removing a new ingress rule:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PreventUpdateOfCoreSecurityGroups",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:************:security-group/sg-1",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:************:security-group/sg-2",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:************:security-group/sg-3",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:************:security-group/sg-4",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:************:security-group/sg-5"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but it's just not jumping out. I'd appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: "Terraform apply" uses resource-level AWS APIs under the hood. So if a user us able to execute "Terraform apply", then this user also has permission to make the same changes in AWS web console or through CLI.

Comment: Aren't you missing this as well?`"arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group-rule/*"`

Comment: As @jellycsc mentioned, the ideal thing to do is to separate the permissions at a user level. So have a Terraform user, which has the access, but no-one else apart from admins have access to this user and block these actions for all other users.

You can use permissions boundary for the same - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html#:~:text=A%20permissions%20boundary%20is%20an,policies%20and%20its%20permissions%20boundaries.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll take a look at this today, and let you know. Looking at something else at the moment, but will definitely get back to you and upvote.

Comment: To clarify... Are you saying that the above rules have been applied to YOUR IAM User, and you are able to modify those security rules? When you modify them, how are you doing it -- is it via the console, or the AWS CLI?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein We use Okta to sign into AWS. When we do, we're presented with a screen that lets us pick a role (read/write/admin) and account to sign in to. For the read and write roles, we want the user to not be able to update any of the security groups. The intent is that if they want to RDC onto a machine, they MUST do it through a bastion server. They should not be able to add in a new Ingress rule that allows them to circumvent the bastion server. This is for government regulations. That's the idea. :)

Comment: So sorry for the delay in responding here, but I got stuck dealing with a couple of issues that were higher priority, and have finally had the chance to work on this again. The issue is resolved. It turns out that I was using the security group name rather than its ID when setting up the policy. So I was using `SecurityGroup` rather than `sg-**********`. Thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a Security Group and added some Inbound and Outbound rules -- worked fine
- Created an IAM User and gave them `AdministrationAccess` permissions -- basically, they can do anything
- The than added an **inline policy** on the user based on your policy:

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PreventUpdateOfCoreSecurityGroups",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:security-group/sg-094f33b4da123b5ae"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `sg-` ID at the end matches the Security Group.

I then tried to add another Inbound rule. I received this message:

> **There was an error modifying your security group inbound rules**
> You may be missing IAM policies that allow AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress. You are not authorized to perform this operation.

So, at least part of the policy seems to be working!

Did you, perhaps, use the *name* of the Security Group in the ARN, rather than the *Security Group ID?*

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, yes! Thanks! Once I had the time to try this again (got stuck with a couple issues that were higher priority), I put in the ID's, and now it works like a charm. Thanks!!!